# newly bought external usb hub not working?

Tags: computer-hardware, computer

i have a newly purchased usb hub powered by an external cable. i plugged in the cable from the hub and then plugged the hub into the laptop, after that switch on the switch to allow electricvity to come through. then i plugged in an external USB hard disk into that slot switched on . the laptop can read it but it shuts off and reads it on again and again. does anybody know why is this? i do have another usb hub already plugged, connected to my keyboard and mouse. is that relevant at all? should i also worry about whether my usb port that didn't work and the new usb hub being fried due to demand more voltage than PC can provide for that port and it overdrew power?

Comment: This isn't really an engineering question but is about use of a commercial device so I think you have asked on the wrong site. I suggest that you pay attention to proper capitalisation and punctuation as it affects legibility and credibility. Meanwhile, you have obviously overloaded the USB hub or laptop port by drawing more current than it is rated for.

Comment: Ask superuser. Probably you need to change your os settings

Comment: You can test for relevance by disconnecting and simplifying the situation.  You should also note the type of usb hub (some usb C ports on laptops might get confused by certain aspects of power).  Test the hd against other computers, ports, etc.